# Magento 2 Cannot extend layout in product page of child theme

Tags: magento, layout, parent-child, magento2

I've created a 'parent' theme that extends from luma & 2 child themes (child-a & child-b) extends from 'parent' theme

In 'child-b' i've created:

- etc
- media
- composer.json
- registration.php
- theme.xml
- Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

After that i created category B and set it's theme to 'child-b'

**Expected result**

the code in default.xml of 'child-b' effect on category B & products on category B

**Actual result**

the code in default.xml of 'child-b' effect ONLY on category B, NOT products on it

I've tried to create other layout file such as catalog_product_view.xml ... but still not work.

Please help me,

Best regard!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a core bug. The same one described in [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8333)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a theme child theme -b to the category B then its only apply for the Category or product list page its not effect the product details page.

If you want to assign custom design for custom products the you need to assign in Admin product edit Go to

**1)_admin->catalog->[select a product] ->Schedule Design Update -> New theme-> [select a theme and save the product]**

Clear cache and reload front of that product